# A property a metric space should have to ensure its open subset does not have an isolated point

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

What is the well-known sufficient condition for the metric space $(X,d)$ to ensure that its open subset $A$ does not have an isolated point?

Here is some condition I made for the question: $\newcommand{\eps}{\epsilon} \newcommand{\ball}[2]{B_{#1}(#2)}$
$$
P_1: \forall x \in X: \forall \eps > 0: \exists y \in X : y \in B_{\eps}(x) \land x \neq y
$$
where $B_\eps (x) = \{y\in X~|~d(x,y) < \eps\}$ is a (open) ball.

Proof: Suppose there is $x \in A$ that is an isolated point of $A$. Then, there is $\eps_1 > 0$ such that $\ball{\eps_1}{x} \cap A =\{x\}$. Since $A$ is open, there is $\eps_2 > 0$ such that $\ball{\eps_2}{x} \subseteq A$. Let $\eps_3 = \min\{\eps_1, \eps_2\}$. Then, $\ball{\eps_3}{x} \cap A = \{x\}$ and ${\ball{\eps_3}{x} \subseteq A}$. Meanwhile, $x\in X$ and $\eps_3 > 0$, which implies that there is $y\in \ball{\eps_3}{x}$ different from $x$ from the condition $P_1$. Therefore, $\ball{\eps_3}{x} \cap A = \{x,y\}$, which is a contradiction.

Is the proof correct? And I wonder what $P_1$ means in topology.

Comment: You mean $\exists y \in A$ instead of $\exists y \in X$ in the condition $P_1$?

Comment: @azif00 It's a property of a metric space $X$ that is not specific to $A$.

Comment: Then how you ensures that $B_{\epsilon_3}(x) \cap A = \{x,y\}$?

Comment: @azif00 From $y \in B_{\epsilon_3}(x) \subseteq  A$.

Comment: I see, then all it's correct. My apologies.

Comment: @azif00 It's totally OK! :)

Comment: @azif00 Is $P_1$ related to completeness of the space?

Comment: @bof I meant the latter one. / No. Any singleton has an isolated point in $X$.

Comment: @bof Thank you for the comment. I am not good at English :(

Comment: @Hermis14: Note that your condition $P_1$ is equivalent to saying that $X$ has no isolated points. More generally, in any topological space it’s true that $X$ has no isolated points if and only if every open subset of $X$ has no isolated points.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you!

Comment: @Hermis14: You’re welcome!